# Find the 5 digits number that arrange from x,x+1,x+2,3x,x+3 so that the number is a perfect square

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers

I'm having a hard time dealing with this problem and here is my approach:

- The perfect square of 5 digits number must be a 3 digits number ( I put it as a,b,c )
- $abc^2$ get us a 5 digits number that written as $a^2$, $2ab$, $2ac+b^2$, $2bc$, $c^2$
- I see that the 2rd and 4th digit are both even
- If I let $x$ be even or odd the 2rd and 4th digit both won't be the same even

So I conclude that the number is not exist. Is my statement wrong? Please help

Comment: $\sqrt{34596}=186$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner ohh hi, how do you do that?

Comment: Isn't that just the matter of checking the numbers $12334, 23465, 34596$ for being perfect squares?

Comment: @StinkingBishop it is pretty hard for me since we have to look for x,x+1,x+2,3x,x+3 and reverse it back

Comment: did you mean the square *root* of a $5$ digit number must be a $3$ digit number?  did you mean $(abc)^2$?  also, note that $c^2$ might be $\ge10$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner that for what I thought

Comment: @user635988 What do you mean by "reverse it back"? Do the digits go in the order $x,x+1, x+2, 3x, x+3$ or in the order $x+3, 3x, x+2, x+1, x$?

Comment: @StinkingBishop it is both

Comment: @StinkingBishop so the answer is not only 1 number

Comment: Ah, well, then you have to check three additional numbers: $43321, 56432$ and $69543$, I guess...

Comment: @StinkingBishop ohh so the only answer is 34596 right? I go check and non is perfect square

Comment: Yes. (Provided that I've correctly understood what you are asking... Let's make sure the question is not, say, about $5$-digit numbers obtained via any *permutation* of those five digits, for example...)

Comment: Wait.... does order matter or not?  You need to include that.  If order matters you only have four options  $00000=0^2$ or $12334$ which is not a perfect square or $23495$ which is not or $34596= 186^2$.  If it has to be reverse then $69543$ is not a perfect square.  But *why* are you saying it needs to be reversed?  No where in the question is that stated.

Comment: "If I let x be even or odd the 2rd and 4th digit both won't be the same even" Why should they be?  $x+1\ne 3x$ so why would the second and third be the same?  And.... did you take into account carrying?  $2ac + b^2< 10$ is not very likely, so you we probably have to carry.

Comment: @user635988 If the order doesn't matter at all, then you have the numbers such as $33124=182^2$...

Comment: Could you *please* actually write what the question actually *is*?

Answer (score 2):

If you say the number has five digits -- the first $x$, the second $x+1$, the third $x+2$, the fourth $3x$, the fifth $x+3$ -- then, for $3x$ to be a single non-zero digit, we need $x=1, 2, $ or $3$.  Can you take it from here?

Comment: It also reverse from x+3,3x,x+2,x+1,x

Comment: Sorry for my bad English

Comment: "It also reverse from x+3,3x,x+2,x+1,x "  Why didn't you *say* so?

Comment: @fleablood sorry for my bad English

Comment: It's not bad english that I mind.  It's simply leaving out important details.  I don't care how *badly* you say it.  But you have to *say* it.